# Create InfluxDB v2 graph for increasing counter value

Tags: influxdb

- I am using the SNMP plugin for the Telegraf agent, to gather a counter value, such as `udpInDatagrams`.
- The data points are being written to InfluxDB v2, running in a Linux container, using Docker.
- The counter value always increases, but never decreases.

Right now, my graph shows the counter value increasing, but never decreasing. My objective is to see the value of the counter per-period, rather than an absolute / lifetime value.

In other words, each value on the graph should be:

```
current_value - last_value
```

[image]

**Question**: How do I create an InfluxDB v2 graph that shows the value of the counter per-period (ie. 10 seconds, 1 minute, 5 minutes), instead of constantly increasing in value?

Answer (score 0):

With Flux there is the [`derivative()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/derivative/) function and with InfluxQL, there is the [`NON_NEGATIVE_DERIVATIVE()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#non_negative_derivative) function, which is in this case preferred over the `DERIVATIVE()` function as the snmp counter can also overflow (reset).